# Django <uuid:id> redefinition error. Pattern Problem

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

i've become an ErrorMessage because i think i have the wrong reference pattern in my url.py.

In my models.py i create this models

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/quiz/quiz'


class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    fk_quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Answer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    fk_quizfrage = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

An in my urls.py i make refernces like this:

```
 path('quiz/<uuid:id>/', QuizDetailView.as_view(), name='quiz-detail'),
```

I think i have to change the pattern from `<uuid:id>`

The complete Error is:

```
:in _parse
    raise source.error(err.msg, len(name) + 1) from None
re.error: redefinition of group name 'uuid' as group 2; was group 1 at position 90
```

Comment: Is this url pattern included in some other url pattern using `include`? Please add that as well.

Comment: No it is not included in an other url.py

Comment: What i mean is is there some urls.py in which you have something like `include('this_app.urls')`?

Comment: Yes i have that. ```path('quiz/', include('quiz.urls')),```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Should your path to this page look like `<localhost or domain name or ip>/quiz/quiz/<uuid:id>/`, or is there anything before the first quiz?

Comment: It works! It was a simple problem. I make first this ```quiz/<uuid:id>``` but after that i make this ```quiz/<uuid:id>/questions/<uuid:id>``` and that was the same uuid. The working code is ```quiz/<uuid:quiz_id>/questions/<uuid:question_id>```